# Website farm apache best practices

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, hosting

I've set up an app which builds new websites.  I am creating virtual host files automatically when a user signs up.

Is there a "right" way to enable the virtual host and reload apache from the web app or should I delegate that task to a cron job with root privileges?  I added www-data to the sudoers folder but I still have a permission denied in my error log.

Ubuntu 11.10 running Apache/Mod_PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like [dynamic vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html) are very useful in your situation.
You don't need to reload apache in case with vhosts at all.

Comment: You're right, this seems like the best path = )